# 410 redirection for specific urls with same ending pattern

Tags: .htaccess, regex

I need help redirecting some thousands old urls to 410 with regex
The url pattern is as follows:

```
https://www.example.com/mc-xxyyzz0-12
```

where the last three characters are always a number, a dash and  other two numbers at the end.

All those URLs must go to 410, I have tried several options but none works as it should.

Comment: I suspect we are talking about apache?

Comment: What is your matching regex? Something like this .*(\d-\d\d)$ ?

Comment: `mc-xxyyzz` - This is a literal string, common to all these URLs? "the last three characters are always a number, a dash and other two numbers at the end." - But that's **four** characters? " I have tried several options" - Please show your current incarnation. Do you have any other directives? (Order is important.)

Comment: #federico yes apache. I've tested "on the fly" espressions found here and there, don't have them with me now.

Comment: #mrwhite yes, of course my mistake. There are four chars at the end: number, dash, number, number. the first three chars are always two letters and a dash (the first two letters can be anything)

Answer (score 0):

To serve a 410 Gone for URLs that follow this URL pattern you could do something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}-xxyyzz\d-\d\d$ - [G]
```

As clarified in comments, this will match a URL-path of the form `/mc-xxyyzz0-12`.

- Where the first two letters are any lowercase letters `a-z`.
- Followed by a hyphen (`-`) and the literal string `xxyyzz` (lowercase only).
- Followed by a digit (0-9), a hypen and two more digits.

If you specifically need a case-insensitive match then include the `NC` (`nocase`) flag on the `RewriteRule`. ie. Change `[G]` to `[NC,G]`.